# Use the ID of the upper select statement in the where clause of the lower select statement in a UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

Data:

Table1:

```
ID          Value1          Date1
 1          foo             2013-04-27
 2          bar             2013-05-01
 3          umm             2013-05-29
 4          ba              2013-06-09
 5          sne             2013-04-30
 6          xyz             2013-07-11
 7          aosid           2013-07-08
```

LinkTable:

```
link        MainID          SubID
 A          1               3
 B          3               1
 A          1               4
 B          4               1
 A          2               6
 B          6               2
```

Query:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Value1, t1.Date1 
from Table1 t1 
where t1.Date1 between '2013-04-24' and '2013-05-08'

union

select t2.ID, t2.Value1, t2.Date1 
from Table1 t2 
where t2.ID in (select LT.SubID 
                from LinkTable LT 
                where LT.link = 'A' and LT.MainID = t1.ID)
```

So this is what I've just tried and I get an error that t1.ID can't be bound. This means I can't use data from the first select in the second one.

Is there a way I can use the ID value from the first select in the second select?

Thanks for all your help.

Desired result:

```
ID        Value1        Date1
 1        foo           2013-04-27
 3        umm           2013-05-29
 4        ba            2013-06-09
 2        bar           2013-05-01
 6        xyz           2013-07-11
 5        sne           2013-04-30
```

So to explain the results a bit better the first select should include all records that are in the date range, now the second select will look to see if it is linked to one of the included records from the first select via the LinkTable.

Comment: @AzizShaikh I added the desired results. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a CTE to help with your logic.

Based on your clarification, I came up with this approach without a union:

```
with ids as (
      select t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t1.Date1 between '2013-04-24' and '2013-05-08' 
     )
select t1.*
from table1 t1 left outer join
     linktable lt
     on t1.id = lt.subid and
        lt.mainid in (select id from ids) 
where lt.mainid is not null or
      t1.Date1 between '2013-04-24' and '2013-05-08'
```

Which you can also rewrite as a union:

```
with ids as (
      select t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t1.Date1 between '2013-04-24' and '2013-05-08' 
     )
select t.*
from ((select * from ids)
      union
      (select *
       from table1 t1 join
            linktable lt
            on t1.id = lt.subid
       where lt.mainid in (select id from ids)
      )
     ) t
```

Comment: 5 is in the result because of the date range, however since 7 is not in the date range and also not in the link table it is out. Basically I want records that are in the date range or if they are not in the date range are they linked to another ID in the LinkTable.

Comment: Thanks so much, I used your first example and it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

No, union sub-queries are independant from each other.
You can quickly modify your query with this one (I've not thought about the best one, just modified your's)

```
select t1.ID, t1.Value1, t1.Date1 
from Table1 t1 
where t1.Date1 between '2013-04-24' and '2013-05-08'

union

select t2.ID, t2.Value1, t2.Date1 
from Table1 t2 
where t2.ID in (select LT.SubID 
            from LinkTable LT 
            left join Table1 t1 on LT.MainID = t1.ID
            where LT.link = 'A' and t1.Date1 between '2013-04-24' and '2013-05-08')
```